# Laravel - I keep getting 'This password reset token is invalid' when I try to reset password

Tags: laravel, passwords

this is my config/auth.php

```
 'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'customers' => [
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'table' => 'customer_password_resets',
            'expire' => 120,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'provider' => 'admins',
            'table' => 'admin_password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
```

when trying to reset customer password , I get the error 'This token is invalid".

This is my ResetsPassword.php -> reset()

```
 public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());


        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );


        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

Here is the password reset request:
[image: password reset request]

Comment: Does your reset.blade.php contain the hidden input with token value?
```<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">```

Comment: Make sure you have `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` this in head tag.

Comment: I have both meta tag and the csrf input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A password reset token must be generated prior to posting to the `password.update` route.  Typically, this occurs when the user enters their email address into a form before being sent a password reset link.

For a custom implementation, you may need to generate the token manually.

```php
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker;

// insert a token record into the password reset table
$token = app(PasswordBroker::class)->createToken($customer);
```

**EDIT:** The token is returned from the broker as an unhashed value, while at the same time, it is stored in the database as a hashed value. Make sure the **unhashed** token value is being submitted to the `reset()` method as the parameter `token` with no underscore, unlike the CSRF `_token`.

Also, your `Customer` model must extend `Authenticatable`.

```php
class Customer extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Is the **unhashed** reset token being sent with the reset request?  `dd($request->all());` and let us see your request data.

Comment: There is no `email` in your request.  You can't have `->credentials()` without an `email` and `password`.

Comment: I tried to add a hidden email field but the value is null

Comment: I would need to see more code to be able to help.  Unless you have it figured out now since the email is the problem.

Comment: Yes. You're right. The issue was email.I've fixed it